# Выборка нескольких категорий одним запросом SQL

Tags: запрос, sql, mysql

Имеется база примерно такого типа:

```
id  |  category  |  login  |  pass  |  count
--------------------------------------------
1   |  1         |  asdas  |  sdas  |  25
2   |  3         |  asdas  |  sdas  |  252
3   |  1         |  asdas  |  sdas  |  255
4   |  4         |  asdas  |  sdas  |  5
5   |  2         |  asdas  |  sdas  |  42
6   |  3         |  asdas  |  sdas  |  42
7   |  3         |  asdas  |  sdas  |  211
```

Требуется, используя всего 1 sql запрос, вывести по одной строке с наименьшей ценой (count), распределяя строки по количеству записей в каждой категории (по убыванию)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное будет что-то вроде этого:

SELECT `category`, MIN(`count`)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `category`
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC